# Correct way to upload weights at inference for faster-rcnn model?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, object-detection, torchvision

I was wondering what is the correct way of uploading saved weights for a trained model at inference.

As an FYI, I train my model using pretrained coco weights and pretrained imagenet weights:

```
model = torchvision.models.detection.fasterrcnn_resnet50_fpn(pretrained=True, pretrained_backbone=True)

num_classes = 2 

# get number of input features for the classifier
in_features = model.roi_heads.box_predictor.cls_score.in_features

# replace the pre-trained head with a new one
model.roi_heads.box_predictor = FastRCNNPredictor(in_features, num_classes)

model.to(device)
```

I then save the model dict in a dictionary where the state is saved like:

```
'state_dict': model.state_dict()
```

Once trained, I upload the weights like:

```
# set up model 
model_test = torchvision.models.detection.fasterrcnn_resnet50_fpn(pretrained=True, pretrained_backbone=True)
num_classes = 2
# get number of input features for the classifier
in_features = model_test.roi_heads.box_predictor.cls_score.in_features
# replace the pre-trained head with a new one
model_test.roi_heads.box_predictor = FastRCNNPredictor(in_features, num_classes)
model_test.to(device)
    
bestmodel = get_best_model(args.best)
bestmodel = torch.load(bestmodel)
model_test.load_state_dict(bestmodel['state_dict'])
```

As you can see, I also upload the pretrained weights at inference (test time). However, you can see that I then upload the weights from my saved model (bestmodel).

I thought by uploading weights, that this would override the initial pretrained weights uploaded. However, when I set the test model to :

```
model_test = torchvision.models.detection.fasterrcnn_resnet50_fpn(pretrained=False, pretrained_backbone= False)
```

And continue to upload my best model, I get slightly worse performance (marginally).

Is there a correct way to upload these weights? And if it shouldn't matter, why do I get a difference?

Comment: how slightly could you add a light to some numbers? cause computers store floating point numbers differently if that's the case there is no luck. please try this one [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html) if this returns true then you're there only.

Comment: basically there is an increase in the number of false positive detections (by about 20) which has a slight impact on accuracy overall. I'm just confused as I thought by loading my model, I override the previous pretrained initialised weights.